# Getting a "this.setState is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I am creating a delete function for my basic todo list application; however I ran into a problem when trying to delete a certain item from the list and setting the state again. It keeps on giving me a `this.setState is not a function` error. The issue is in `deleteTodo(id)`.

My TodoStore.js

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";
import * as TodoActions from "../actions/TodoActions";

class TodoStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this)
    this.state = { todos: [
      {
        id: 113464613,
        text: "Go Shopping"
      },
      {
        id: 235684679,
        text: "Pay Water Bill"
      },
    ]};
  }

  createTodo(text) {
    const id = Date.now();

    this.state.todos.push({
      id,
      text,
    });

    this.emit("change");
  }

  deleteTodo(id) {
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => id !== todo.id)
    console.log(todos)
    this.setState({
      todos: todos
    })
    this.emit("change")
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.state.todos;
  }

  handleActions(action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case "CREATE_TODO": {
        this.createTodo(action.text);
        break;
      }
      case "DELETE_TODO": {
        this.deleteTodo(action.id);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}

const todoStore = new TodoStore;
dispatcher.register(todoStore.handleActions.bind(todoStore));
window.dispatcher = dispatcher
export default todoStore;
```

Error message in the console:

```
TodoStore.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: _this.setState is not a function
    at TodoStore._this.deleteTodo (TodoStore.js:46)
    at TodoStore._this.handleActions (TodoStore.js:63)
    at Dispatcher._invokeCallback (Dispatcher.js:198)
    at Dispatcher.dispatch (Dispatcher.js:174)
    at Object.deleteTodo [as b] (TodoActions.js:11)
    at Todos.deleteTodo (Todos.js:34)
    at onClick (Todos.js:51)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:145)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:195)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:248)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:262)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:593)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:615)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:713)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:724)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:694)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:855)
    at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:864)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:4857)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:17498)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2189)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4936)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:17553)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2208)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4913)
```

Comment: I think this is because of the binding issues. Try to write all functions as arrow functions and see if works.

Comment: And also you should not mutate state directly.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try now, but I thought adding `this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this)` in the constructor would fix it.

Comment: How else should I do it?

Comment: `deleteTodo = (id) => {...}`

Comment: I know how to change it in an arrow function, I was asking about not mutating the state directly

Comment: Also changing all the functions into arrow functions does not fix the issue

Comment: in createtod you are pushing directly into state, which is wrong, you should use setstate instead

Comment: @razvanusc you should make a copy first and than use setState

Comment: Yea, but could this affect the delete function too? I'm asking because for me currently it doesn't matter if I push directly because that will be changed later when I will be using an API

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'd declare the class as a React Component, without this you won't be able to have "state" nor will you be able to access the setState function (which is the one that creates the new state).

Then I wouldn't bind the functions, just in each one of the functions that you would like to declare inside the class I would do it in the following way that I indicate you in the code:

`nameOfFunction = () =>`

With this form ([arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) you get the scope and therefore be able to use this to access the state.

Finally, when you push to add a new element this is PROHIBITED in React. The state is immutable and you can only create a new state to make any changes, so we use setState and we help ourselves of the ...this.state.todos ([spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)).

It does this by creating a new array and adding the object you need with id and text.

I hope I helped you.
Best,

```
class TodoStore extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          todos: [
            {
              id: 113464613,
              text: "Go Shopping",
            },
            {
              id: 235684679,
              text: "Pay Water Bill",
            },
          ],
        };
      }

      createTodo = text => {
        const id = Date.now();

        this.setState({
          todos: [...this.state.todos, { id, text }],
        });

        this.emit("change");
      };

      deleteTodo = id => {
        const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => id !== todo.id);
        console.log(todos);

        this.setState({
          todos,
        });

        this.emit("change");
      };

      getAll = () => this.state.todos;

      handleActions = action => {
        switch (action.type) {
          case "CREATE_TODO": {
            this.createTodo(action.text);
            break;
          }
          case "DELETE_TODO": {
            this.deleteTodo(action.id);
            break;
          }
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: But I need to extend `EventEmitter` as this is my `TodoStore`. How else could I get the `setState` function?

Comment: Is there a way to change this by not using `state`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd put in a simple React class for you to see the example.

Try changing that "extend" for the one you had or if it doesn't work, try adding this inside the builder:

`this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();`

Comment: When extending `EventEmitter` the functions don't work because of the `setState`; however when extending `React.Component` nothing loads as I'm getting errors from different components. Where should I try adding `this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();`? I'm asking as I'm a bit confused by the issue.

Comment: EventEmitter is a class of the module "events" that has nothing to do with React so extending it doesn't let you use state as it does not belong to this library.

1. Import: `import { EventEmitter } from "events"` . And then you declare an attribute this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter() 


2. What I think you could do is create this class as a child of a container that was a React class and through props send to the container what you want to change or modify.

Here is an example that uses this class with React components:
https://gist.github.com/mhart/6ca15a54541caae04a075db76b68c06c

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this error is because you don't get access to the this object of the class inside the class methods. To overcome this use `bind(this)` in your constructor where you want to use set state.

```
constructor(){
 super();
 this.state={};
 this.createTodo=this.createTodo.bind(this);
 this.deleteTodo=this.deleteTodo.bind(this);
 this.getAll=this.getAll.bind(this);
 this.handleActions=this.handleActions.bind(this);
}
```

You can also use arrow functions to use this inside the functions.
For example

```
createTodo = (text) => {

 }
```

Comment: I've tried this but no success, now getting a `_this.setState is not a function` error

Answer (score 0):

**EventEmitter** class don't have **this.setState** function. If you want to use that, you must be in a React.Component.

In the case. I think you can **setState** when you listen the emit -> **change**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `setState`, if the class does not extend the Component from React. However, you don't really need setState here, since what you did is actually just a "service" and not a React Component.

You can just use your own internal "state" variable, you can call it `todos` since it hold only a list of todos. For setting it, you shouldn't mutate it, but create a new object from the old one and merge it with the new values:

`this.todos = [ ...this.todos, { id, text } ]`

Or you can use `concat`:

`this.todos = this.todos.concat({ id, text })`

Same thing for delete, you just use filter.